# Is it possible to obtain a Schengen visa and a UK visa together?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I am from India. I have planned to visit my friends in the UK. From there we have planned to visit Switzerland and Germany.

Is it possible for me to take both visas together in India?

Comment: Why would you think that isn't possible ??

Comment: This is the first time am travelling ! So am not sure about the rules !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it possible for me to take both visas together in India?**

This is certainly possible, but at the moment (March 2016) China is the only country where both UK and Schengen applications can be generated from *a single form*.  All other countries require the end-user to complete both applications separately.  See [Obtaining a UK and Schengen Visa in a Single Application or Single Step in China](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49636/obtaining-a-uk-and-schengen-visa-in-a-single-application-or-single-step-in-china).  It is unlikely that the pilot test will extend to India at least until 2020, if then.

For your Schengen application, please read

- [Schengen Visa Application: tips for preparing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-tips-for-preparing)
- [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen
  Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

and for the UK...

- [Which standard visa should i apply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64049/which-standard-visa-should-i-apply/64050#64050)

As a general rule of thumb, you would complete the applications according to which locale you plan to visit first, but that's a *suggestion only*.

See also: [Visiting both Schengen and the UK. Which visa should apply for first?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60406/visiting-both-schengen-and-the-uk-which-visa-should-apply-for-first) related, but not answered yet.